# iOS Xcode NSURL too many arguments

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurl

In my code I am trying to send some data to my PHP file

For adding stuff into my SQL i use the GET method.

So far I need to use a form on the website, but I'd like to add data with just browsing to it, such as:

http://server.com/add.php?user=some data here&message= last data here

I am trying to use this code so far:

```
 NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone App&message=%@",
                                 messageBox.text]; 

 [messageView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:add]];
```

However Xcode tells me: "Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2"

Comment: Keep in mind you will also need to escape your string to remove spaces, making the HTTP request with the space in iPhone App will screw up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone App&message=";
NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",escapedString, messageBox.text]];
[messageView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:add]];
```

You should be using `NSString +stringWithFormat:`

Comment: Many thanks! However, how do I make the app the remove the spaces? It worked when I replaced a + with the spaces

Answer (score 0):

URLWithString accepts strings , or string literals. 
This is how you should do it :

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone App&message=%@", messageBox.text];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];  
[messageView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:add]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone App&message=%@", messageBox.text]];
```

That's because URLWithString: expects only one argument of NSString * type. Use NSString's +stringWithFormat: method to make an NSString object from formatted string and arguments.